# Difference between core function use multiple times vs constant for get USER ID

Tags: wordpress, function, constants

I need multiple place current logged-in user ID. When I need user ID use get_current_user_id() function. I think it will create performance issue. So i think to assign user ID to constant and use wherever want.

Is this correct?. This constant work faster than a function call.?

Answer (score 1):

It might be very, very slightly faster, but probably not so much faster as to be even measurable.

It's probably good practice to store the current user ID locally if you're using it multiple times in the course of a single function, but if you're talking about storing it to use across multiple functions, I wouldn't got down that route. Some example code from you would be helpful in knowing what you're proposing, exactly.

You won't gain much, because `get_current_user_id()` ends up calling [_wp_get_current_user()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/user.php#L2496), which, as you can see from the source code, caches the User object in a global the first time it's called, so you're only really saving a few lines of code and a couple of function calls.

Effectively, it's already doing what you're suggesting: saving the result in an object in memory so it doesn't need to go work it out/fetch details from the database every time. You'd almost certainly get vastly more performance improvement of your site as whole by making sure you've got opcache turned on, or sticking Varnish in front of it, or installing mod_pagespeed in Apache, or using a CDN, or whatever.

"Premature optimisation is the root of all evil". Are you actually *having* any performance problems? If not, don't worry about this kind of micro-optimisation until you do.

(And anyone reading your code will have to work out what odd thing you're doing for this micro-optimisation, whereas if they see a `get_current_user_id()` call they'll know for certain what's going on if they're in the least familiar with WordPress.)